Easy (graphic) interpretation of the third isomorphism theorem of groups
I came across these slides today and this diagram is shown when the third isomorphism theorem was presented.

Could somebody please provide an intuitive way to explain the picture? Why do the green boxes disappear?
I am familiar with the formal statement of the theorem, but I would like an explanation using this diagram that would be accessible to someone who has not yet learned the theorem.

Notice: This picture only explains a bijection $(G/N)/(H/N) \cong G/H$, not that there is an isomorphism of groups. It also will not capture why we need that $N$ and $H$ are normal in $G$. (It is a funny exercise to expand the picture accordingly. Writing down the two-line proof* symbolically is easier, though.) Accordingly, I will only speak of the underlying sets below.
Let's start with image 1.
The (underlying set of the) group $G$ (black box) is decomposed into several cosets of $H$ (orange boxes). In the picture, there are three of these. One of these is $H$ (the one in the bottom). The others are just "translates" $gH$ of $H$ (this picture works very well for the quotient group $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}$). This is why all the orange boxes look the same. Inside $H$, we have the subgroup $N$. Now we may just zoom into that box and apply what we already know. We can decompose it into several (in the picture: two) cosets of $N$ (green boxes), one of which is $N$, and they all look the same. The group $N$ has a certain number of elements (in the picture: four), depicted as black dots. Each coset of $N$ in $H$ will have the same number of elements.
Let's look at image 2.
We can also forget about the orange boxes (representing $H$) and just treat $N$ as a subgroup of $G$. The cosets are the green boxes, six in total.
What does the quotient group $G/N$ do? It basically collapses every element of $N$ to just one element. And accordingly, it does the same in every coset of $N$, say to a chosen representative of that coset. Basically, in every coset, all its elements become indistinguishable from another. You can maybe even imagine an animation from image 1 to image 2 that "dissolves" the black dots, fades them into a green color, until each coset is just one big green square.
With $H/N$, we do something similar. In $H$ (and, accordingly, in every $G$-coset of $H$) we only have two cosets of $N$ now, but basically it's the same.
To get from image 2 to image 3, we repeat the same process, just "on a higher level". To construct $G/N$ modulo $H/N$, instead of collapsing elements (black dots), we now collapse the cosets (green squares). The result is, again, that you "blur" them away and end up with the three orange boxes.
To see that this is the same as $G/H$, it helps to add another picture.

I have just removed all references to $N$. As you see, when we now do the quotient process, the black dots "blur" away and each orange box just becomes one thing. And this is exactly what we got before.
*Here is the two-line proof, using the Yoneda Lemma:
$\hom((G/N)/(H/N),-) \cong \{f \in \hom(G/N,-) : f|_{H/N} = 1\} \\ \cong \{g \in \hom(G,-) : g|_N = 0, g|_H = 1 \} = \{g \in \hom(G,-) : g|_H = 1\} \cong \hom(G/H,-) ~ \checkmark$

I got a downvote one minute after posting this. Wow. Any explanation @downvoter? Have you even read the whole thing?
